# Php to return on main page after script is over

Tags: php, upload

I am uploading an image by putting an upload button (which has php script-upload.php) under the image. When the upload button is pressed, image gets uploaded but the page moves to upload.php. I want that image goes away on the main page and it should show that image has been uploaded instead of showing upload.php. Please help me.

Comment: Can you show some code?  Preferably the minimum amount of code necessary to reproduce the problem?  Chances are a simple redirect will work for you, but it's difficult to tell from your description.

Comment: To repeat what David has said, how about showing us the code you're using. When you've done that flag to re-open.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make your `upload.php` script redirect back to the original page.

#### On upload.php

```
// Set a session variable indicating successful upload
sesssion_start();
$_SESSION['upload_success'] = TRUE;
// Redirect back to the previous page
// Substitute your correct URL
header("Location: http://example.com/index.php");
exit();
```

#### On your main page

```
// Retrieve the session variable and display success message
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['upload_success']) && $_SESSION['upload_success']) {
  echo "File uploaded successfully";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `header("Location: http://yoursite.com/anotherpage.php")` in order to redirect an user to another page

Answer (score 0):

In PHP / HTML and submitting a form (to upload.php) you force the browser to go there. You cannot handle File Upload directly in Javascript, so there is no way to stay on this site.

Use a 303-Redirect header in PHP or a meta - Redirection to the main page, but this will only take place AFTER the file is fully uploaded.

You can use Javascript and open a new Window / Frame to send the file and stay on the site.